# Photoshop rename to layer name

Tags: applescript, rename, photoshop

I need a script to choose a folder, open the Photoshop files in the folder, then rename the files to the current name of layer plus the file extension. (Each of the layers will be named differently as the images have been created with a data merge. All I have so far is opening one image and getting the layer name, I can't figure out the repeat and the rename of the file:

```
set inputFolder to choose folder
tell application "Finder"
    set filesList to files in inputFolder
    set myDoc to item 1 of filesList as string
    tell application "Adobe Photoshop CC"
        set display dialogs to never
        open alias myDoc
    end tell
end tell
tell application "Adobe Photoshop CC"
    set layerName to name of current layer of current document as string
    -- close current document saving no
    return layerName as string
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this :

```
set inputFolder to choose folder
activate application "Adobe Photoshop CC"
tell application "Finder"
    set filesList to document files in inputFolder
    repeat with tFile in filesList
        set nExtension to name extension of tFile
        set layerName to my getLayerName(tFile as string)
        if layerName is not "" then
            set newName to (layerName & "." & nExtension)
            if newName is not name of tFile then -- else the name is already the layer name
                set i to 1
                repeat while exists item newName in inputFolder -- if same name in the folder (maybe same layer name)
                    set newName to (layerName & i & "." & nExtension)
                    set i to i + 1
                end repeat
                set name of tFile to newName
            end if
        end if
    end repeat
end tell

on getLayerName(myDoc)
    tell application "Adobe Photoshop CC"
        set display dialogs to never
        open alias myDoc
        repeat 5 times
            tell current document to if exists then
                set layerName to (name of current layer) as string
                close saving no
                return layerName
            end if
            delay 1
        end repeat
    end tell
    return "" -- no document
end getLayerName
```

Answer (score 0):

Brilliant that works a treat, just trying to backward engineer the script, in the photoshop function the repeat 5 times will that limit the script to only work with 5 files? and the variable tFile is that a constant as the variable doesn't seem to be declared?
Still quite new to this so forgive my lack of knowledge and thanks again